# How to Perform Multiple Action on Single Click in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, action

I have a Question on performing other `buttons` action with single `button` click. Some example code for three buttons:

```
JButton a = new JButton("a");
a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Action of a is Here                   
  }
});

JButton b = new JButton("b");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Action of b is Here                   
  }
});
```

Those should come together, like:

```
JButton c = new JButton("c");
c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Action of c is Here
    // Action of a 
    // Action of b              
   }
});
```

In the above example i have three buttons `a,b,c` with its own action; but as you can see, C also has to run the actions of A and B. What are good ways to address this?

Comment: I have just add a 4th solution to my answer, I still need to validate it but this shouls works fine.

Comment: Hey sorry for that man, am new to Stackoverflow Just Check my Reputation and Badges, i was really happy for your edit, but seriously i don't know how to apply changes. please please can you help me with that. seriously i dint mean it.

Comment: Never mind: that is why I am aksing. So: you "click" on the line that says "edited at ...". That gives you the full list of edits that happened to your question. Now, if you want to simply bring back a certain version, you turn to that version and click the "rollback" link. That is what I just did; now that we agree, that your rollback wasn't intentionally.

Comment: And as you can see, the reworked content is back; and my "complaints" to you are gone. But as said: one thing to understand: you want to describe your *problem* in your question. For good or bad, content such as "greeting / thanks / important problem / help me" ... is simply discouraged here ;-)

Comment: Doing mistakes means learning new stuff. but mistakes must be done only once. so @GhostCat you taught me some new things, thanks for that. this wont repeat again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are all correct, but there is one important aspect missing here: be careful about dong "too many things" on the [AWT event dispatcher thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Meaning: when a button is clicked, an **event** gets created, and the UI framework uses that special thread to trigger the registered listeners. If one of the listeners now decides to do a intensive computation ... the UI event threads stays busy doing "that". And while doing "that thing"; this thread isn't available to dispatch any **other** UI event.

So, this is "not only" about creating methodA(), methodB(), methodC() and invoking them in your third action listener. It is also about understanding *if* combining multiple calls becomes subject to "I should better run those things in a **separate** thread; to not block the event dispatcher thread".

In that sense: the other answers tell you where to go from here; but be really careful about the "amount of activity" that your "joined actions" button is about to create!

Comment: I didn't really thought about that in this question but this really need to be mention ! I generaly stop huge process if this is noticable, so above 1/30s of process. Below, this won't be notice by human eye so should not be a problem (not a rule, just mine)

Comment: The point is: having it work one day doesn't mean it wont be noticeable tomorrow or in the future. The other day I saw a person doing a **database query** within the action listener. That might work *nicely* in your dev setup. But in other situations, just waiting for a connection object from the pool might easily stall for many seconds. And all of a sudden, "surprisingly" the UI client freezes. And the paying client gets on the phone to call your support team.

Comment: Ah ah ah ah unfortunatly I have seen something similar... off course that was not part of my rule but any process that requires external resource, meaning growing time process or waiting time, is not part of that logic!

Answer (score 2):

**1) Methods**

Use methods for each action and call those in the `ActionListener.actionPerformed`

```
public void methodA(){}
public void methodB(){
    methodA();
}
```

**2) Action instance**

You could create your own classes of `ActionListener` to perform the actions

First action :

```
class ActionA implements ActionListener{
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          ...
    }
}
```

An improved action

```
class ActionB extends ActionA{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           super.actionPerformed(e);  //Will call the first action
           ...
    }
}
```

This is limited since you can't have multiple extends but is also a nice solution

**3) Click**

Last but I don't like it, use [`AbstractButton.doClick`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick()) to dynamicly click on other buttons.

**4) Add multiple action**

Just notice that the methods is not a `setActionListener` but a `addActionListener` meaning that it will accept multiple ActionListener.

So define create two instances

```
ActionListener listenerA = new ActionLisener ..
ActionListener listenerB = new ActionLisener ..

buttonA.addActionListener(listenerA);

buttonB.addActionListener(listenerB);

buttonC.addActionListener(listenerA);
buttonC.addActionListener(listenerB);
```

With a small test, I notice that the actions are execute in the order B -> A (might not be a generality).

As said in comment, this should be us knowing the risk, this will . If an action failed because of an exception, should the next one be executed ? By default it won't because the process will not hide exceptions.

I would restrict this solution to GUI management like reseting fields, disabling, ... that could be use in different buttons.

Comment: I would be careful about option4 ... sure, that works. But well, it distributes "responsibility" in a way that is not very transparent.

Comment: @GhostCat clearly! I would limit this to GUI management like enabling/disabling fields, clear textfields, ... but not business logic. This would be impossible to manage the action to execute and exception handling

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you want to do on Button click a, you can put in a method and call it from wherever you want.

```
public void methodForA(){
   // do here what you want
}
```

You can call this now in the methods you want it to call from. In your case from button click A and button click C

```
JButton a = new JButton("a");
a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        methodForA();
    }
 });

// and also in your c-Button
JButton c = new JButton("c");
c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          // Action of c is Here
          methodForA(); 
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefan Lindner  that so easy than i expected simple logic, thanks a lot man really am glad. +1, that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Create 3 methods for each button indepently from the actionListeners action Perform method and call them from the actionPerfomed methods:

```
private void btnAClicked(){};
private void btnBClicked(){};
private void btnCClicked(){};


JButton c = new JButton("c");
    c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           btnCClicked();
           btnAClicked(); 
           btnBClicked();              

        }
    });
```